# Replacing 0's with 1's in a data frame

Tags: python-3.x

I have a data frame `df`  which has columns `A,B,C,D,...,X,Y,Z` and I wish to replace all `0` entries with `1` in all but columns `C` and `D`.

The following code that I am have attempted is:

`df[df.columns[~df.columns.isin(['C','D'])]].replace(0,1,inplace=True)`

but it is not working.

New to coding so any help here would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

get the column names as list.

```
col_list = df.columns.tolist()
```

remove the columns C and D.

```
 dont=['C','D']
 for ele in sorted(dont, reverse = True):  
 del col_list[ele]
```

iterate over all the columns with replace function

```
for i in df[col_list].columns:
    df[i].replace(0,1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a data frame df which has columns A,B,C,D,...,X,Y,Z and I wish
>   to replace all 0 entries with 1 in all but columns C and D.

```
# Save the columns
c = df['C']
d = df['D']

# Remove the columns
df.drop('C', axis=1, inplace=True)
df.drop('D', axis1=, inplace=True)

# Make your replacement
df.replace(0, 1)

# Replace the columns
df['C'] = c
df['D'] = d
```